# Sum Columns Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written the following PowerShell script for getting disk space information for servers in our environment.

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content E:\POC.txt
$array = @()
foreach($server in $servers){
    $sysinfo =  Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $server
    for($i = 0;$i -lt $sysinfo.Count; $i++){
        $sname =  $sysinfo[$i].SystemName
        $servername = $server
        $label = $sysinfo[$i].Label
        if(($label) -and (!($label.Contains("FILLER")))){
            write-host "Processing $label from $server"
            $name = $sysinfo[$i].Name
            $capacity = [math]::round(($sysinfo[$i].Capacity/1GB),2)
            $fspace = [math]::round(($sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace/1GB),2)
            $sused = [math]::round((($sysinfo[$i].Capacity - $sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace)/1GB),2)
            $fspacepercent =  [math]::Round((($sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace*100)/$sysinfo[$i].Capacity),2)
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SystemName" -Value $sname
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerName" -Value $server
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Label" -Value $label
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $name
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Capacity(GB)" -Value $capacity
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FreeSpace(GB)" -Value $fspace
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Used(GB)" -Value $sused
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FreeSpace%" -Value $fspacepercent
            $array += $obj
        }
    }
    $array += write-output " "
    $totalSize = ($array | Measure-Object 'Capacity(GB)' -Sum).Sum
    $array += $totalsize
    $array += write-output " "
}
$filename = "E:\VolumeReport.csv"
$array |  Export-CSV $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

One additional requirement here is to get the sum of the columns for Capacity, Size and Freespace for each server. I tried using Measure-Object but no success. 
No values are getting outputted here. Just blank. Please look into this and kindly assist.

Comment: Is it just the totals that don't work? How do you intend to include that in the csv?

Comment: Do you need to run this on PowerShell v2?  You're doing the very, very lengthy Add-Member method of solving this problem, which could be so much simpler and shorter using the v3 and up approach.

Comment: @Matt:It's Just the totals that don't work. I have just put up my revised code for calculating totals.

Comment: @FoxDeploy: I have to run it on V2. Coz our centralized server has not been updated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try this on for size shall we.

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content E:\POC.txt
$propertyOrdered = "SystemName","ServerName","Label","Name","Capacity(GB)","FreeSpace(GB)","Used(GB)","FreeSpace%"
$filename = "C:\temp\VolumeReport.csv"
('"{0}"' -f ($propertyOrdered -join '","')) | Set-Content $filename

foreach($server in $servers){
    $sysinfo =  Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $server
    $serverDetails = @()

    for($i = 0;$i -lt $sysinfo.Count; $i++){
        $sname =  $sysinfo[$i].SystemName
        $servername = $server
        $label = $sysinfo[$i].Label
        if(($label) -and (!($label.Contains("FILLER")))){
            write-host "Processing $label from $server"
            $name = $sysinfo[$i].Name
            $capacity = [math]::round(($sysinfo[$i].Capacity/1GB),2)
            $fspace = [math]::round(($sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace/1GB),2)
            $sused = [math]::round((($sysinfo[$i].Capacity - $sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace)/1GB),2)
            $fspacepercent =  [math]::Round((($sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace*100)/$sysinfo[$i].Capacity),2)
            $props = @{
                "SystemName" = $sname
                "ServerName" = $server
                "Label" = $label
                "Name" = $name
                "Capacity(GB)" = $capacity
                "FreeSpace(GB)" = $fspace
                "Used(GB)" = $sused
                "FreeSpace%" = $fspacepercent
            }
            # Build this server object.
            $serverDetails += New-Object PSObject -Property $props
        }
    } 

    # Output current details to file. 
    $serverDetails | Select $propertyOrdered | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content $filename
    #Calculate Totals and append to file.
    $totals = '"","","","Totals",{0},{1},{2},""' -f ($serverDetails | Measure-Object -Property "Capacity(GB)" -Sum).Sum,
        ($serverDetails | Measure-Object -Property "FreeSpace(GB)" -Sum).Sum,
        ($serverDetails | Measure-Object -Property "Used(GB)" -Sum).Sum
    $totals | Add-Content $filename 
}
```

Part of the issue here is that you were mixing object output and static string output which most likely would have been holding you back. I tidied up the object generation in a way that should be 2.0 compliant. Not that what you were going was wrong in anyway but this is a little more pleasing to the eye then all the `Add-Member`s

I removed `$array` since it did not have a place anymore since the logic here is constantly output data to the output file as supposed to storing it temporarily.

For every `$server` we build an array of disk information in the variable `$serverDetails`. Once all the disks have been calculated (using your formulas still) we then create a totals line. You were not really clear on how you wanted your output so I guessed. The above code should net output like the following. (It looks a lot nicer in Excel or in a csv aware reader. )

```
"SystemName","ServerName","Label","Name","Capacity(GB)","FreeSpace(GB)","Used(GB)","FreeSpace%"
"server01","server01","System Reserved","\\?\Volume{24dbe945-3ea6-11e0-afbd-806e6f6e6963}\","0.1","0.07","0.03","71.85"
"","","","Totals",0.1,0.07,0.03,""
"server02","server02","System Reserved","\\?\Volume{24dbe945-3ea6-11e0-afbd-806e6f6e6963}\","0.1","0.07","0.03","69.27"
"server02","server02","images","I:\","1953.12","152.1","1801.02","7.79"
"server02","server02","Data","E:\","79.76","34.59","45.18","43.36"
"","","","Totals",2032.98,186.76,1846.23,""
```

Comment: Please review my revised code for calculating totals.

Comment: I need totals to get computed for each server and not all severs at once. going by your suggestion, it is computing all the totals for all the servers mentioned in the txt files. Please look into this and suggest an edit accordingly. Also after trying your code, still no totals are getting outputted to the CSV file. Just blank. Nothing else

Comment: Ok sorry about that I misunderstood. Need more significant changes for that. No Problem we can fix this.

Comment: @user2068804 have a look again please.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the total of the columns for all the servers at the end of for-each loop and output the same?? Please comment and if possible suggest an edit accordingly.

Comment: Yes. The simple thing to do would be keep 3 variables adding that data for each pass. Then at the end output one last line. Try it yourself and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have modified the code and it's working perfect